# Load all nested children from same collection

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection with documents containing references to children from same collection.

Collection of **Components**:

```
 [
  {
    "_id": "group01",
    "type": "Group",
    "children": [
      {
        "_id": "list01",
        "order": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "list02",
        "order": 1
      }
    ],
    "order": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "list01",
    "type": "List",
    "children": [],
    "order": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "list02",
    "type": "List",
    "children": [
      {
        "_id": "item01",
        "order": 0
      }
    ],
    "order": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "item01",
    "type": "Item",
    "children": [],
    "order": 0
  }
]
```

Model for Component:

```
[BsonCollection(collectionName: "Components")]
public class Component {

  [JsonProperty("_id")]
  [BsonElement("_id")]
  [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof (StringObjectIdGenerator))]
  public string Id { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("type")]
  [BsonElement("type")]
  [BsonRequired]
  public string Type { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("order")]
  [BsonElement("order")]
  public int? Order { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("children")]
  [BsonElement("children")]
  [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
  public List <Component> Children { get; set; }

}
```

While loading the document, I need to load all the nested children for a given id. For example, to get document with **_id: group01**, I want to fetch all the properties of children nested to all levels like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "group01",
    "type": "Group",
    "children": [
      {
        "_id": "list01",
        "type": "List",
        "children": [],
        "order": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "list02",
        "type": "List",
        "children": [
          {
            "_id": "item01",
            "type": "Item",
            "children": [],
            "order": 0
          }
        ],
        "order": 0
      }
    ],
    "order": 0
  }
]
```

I am able to get this with recursively populating children but this will take more time when there are more levels in the hierarchy.

```
public override async Task <Component> GetByIdAsync(Guid id) {
    try {

        var Components = (MongoCollectionBase<Component>)_dbRepository.GetCollection<Component>();
        Component component = await Components.Find(i => i.Id == id.ToString()).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        for (var i = 0; i < component.Children.Count; i++) {
            component.Children[i] = await GetByIdAsync(Guid.Parse(component.Children[i].Id));
        }
        return component;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        _logger.LogException(ex, $ "Exception while reading component: {id}", id.ToString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

How to achieve this in a more optimized way with aggregation/projection? Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to load the hierarchy using an aggregate with a `$graphLookup`, you can use the following pipeline:

```
var result = await Components.Aggregate()
  .Match(Builders<Component>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, "group01"))
  .GraphLookup<Component, string, string, string, Component, IEnumerable<Component>, Component>(
    Components,
    "children._id",
    "_id",
    "$children._id",
    "children",
    "depth")
  .ToListAsync();
```

The result contains the requested parent with all children and is retrieved from the database in a single request.

For this to work, I adjusted the model:

- Removed `BsonRequired` from `Type`
- Added `Depth` property

---

```
public class Component
{

    [JsonProperty("_id")]
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    [BsonElement("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("order")]
    [BsonElement("order")]
    public int? Order { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("children")]
    [BsonElement("children")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public List<Component> Children { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("depth")]
    public int Depth { get; set; }
}
```